# PHP json_encode issue with array 0 key

Tags: php, arrays, key, json

I am having a problem using json_encode to generate a json encoded string from an array.

The section of the array in question looks like this

```
RatingDistribution (Array, 11 elements)
    0 (Array, 1 element)
        0 (String, 3 characters ) 4.5
    1 (Array, 1 element)
        1 (String, 4 characters ) 11.9
    2 (Array, 1 element)
```

But produces this in the string:

```
"RatingDistribution":[["4.5"],{"1":"11.9"},
```

I would expect this:

```
"RatingDistribution":[{"0":"4.5"},{"1":"11.9"},
```

All I'm doing is this:

```
$result = json_encode($array);
```

Have I done something wrong or do I need more code to ensure the 0 key is present?

Cheers
Andy

Comment: can you post the php code where you get the array? or print_r the array? Looks like your forearch is wrong.

Comment: I think it screws up on the second element (index 1) becuase it's sub array starts as 1 and thus gets interpreted as a string key.

Answer (score 23):

The result you are getting should be expected; `json_encode` detects that you are only using numeric keys in the array, so it translates that to an array instead of an object in JSON. Most of the time, that's exactly what you want to do.

If for some reason you don't (why?), in PHP >= 5.3 you can use the [`JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) flag to get your desired output:

```
$result = json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Comment: the behaviour is a little odd, for example the first value will decode to an array where all subsequent values will be objects.

Comment: I suspect we will have to use JSON_FORCE_OBJECT

Comment: @user2147830: Not really odd IMHO. The second array's first key is not `0`, which is enough for the heuristic to decide "OK, this is an associative array".

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use arrays in your json then instead of [`JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) parameter you can simply cast array to object.

Problem:

```
json_encode([0 => [1,2,3]]); // Return: [[1,2,3]]
json_encode(["0" => [1,2,3]]); // Return: [[1,2,3]]
json_encode([1 => [1,2,3]]); // Return: {"1":[1,2,3]}
```

Not what we expect :

```
json_encode([0 => [1,2,3]], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); // Return: {"0":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3}}
```

Solution:

```
json_encode((object)[0 => [1,2,3]]); // Return: {"0":[1,2,3]}
json_encode(new \ArrayObject([0 => [1,2,3]])); // Return: {"0":[1,2,3]}
```

Comment: this work also in sub-array, such us `['a' => (object)['0' => 'test']]` even

Comment: @RobertoBisello this is probably the simplest solution if you don't want to apply JSON_FORCE_OBJECT parameter to the whole array

Answer (score -2):

Cou can try to cast the array key to a string for example with strval or (string).

Comment: That was my first thought but it made no difference, enclosing it in quotes does but it makes very messy json :)